# what do zero real parts of eigenvalues mean? Any good references?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, eigenvalues, stability, hyperbolic-pde, advection

I am solving a 1D advection problem of the the form
$$dQ/dt=[A]Q$$
where {Q} is the vector of unknowns and [A] is the matrix of coefficients of spatial discretisation. I have worked out the eigenvalues of [A] to get an idea about the stability of the semi-discretised system and I am getting eigenvalues with zero real parts plus imaginary parts. Are there any good references for this?

Answer (score 5):

Eigenvalues with zero eigenvalue correspond to purely oscillatory modes. You can see it by diagonalising the system. Your matrix $A$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
A = P \Sigma P^{-1}
\end{equation}
where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $\lambda_n$ corresponding to the eigenvalues of $Q$. You can now transform your ODE to
\begin{equation}
dQ/dt = P \Sigma P^{-1} Q \Rightarrow d (P^{-1}Q)/dt = \Sigma \left( P^{-1} Q \right)
\end{equation}
since $A$ and thus $P$ do not depend on $t$. In the transformed coordinate $R:=P^{-1}Q$. the system decouples into 
\begin{equation}
  dR/dt = \Sigma R
\end{equation}
and thus, as $\Sigma$ is diagonal, into a number of independent ODEs
\begin{equation}
  d r_n / dt = \lambda_n r_n
\end{equation}
with $r_n$ the n-th entry of $R$. This scalar ODE has the solution
\begin{equation}
r_n(t) = r_n(0) \exp(\lambda_n t)
\end{equation}
By Euler's formula, for $\lambda_n = i a_n$, i.e. zero real part, this becomes
\begin{equation}
  r_n(t) = r_n(0) \left( \cos(a_n t) + i\sin(a_n t) \right).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3):

In the 2-D case, this corresponds to an elliptic fixed point (an orbital, I believe).

You might look into Lyapunov stability, hopefully someone will be able to recommend a good resource on that.

I'll try to have another look later to see if I can find resources on this.

**UPDATE**

For related material, you might look into limit cycles, or the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem. I've managed to find a reference for the latter. You might also try searching on math.stackexchange for dynamical systems references.

*Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos* -  Hirsch, Smale, Devaney

Comment: Thanks Roland, I think I've found good book  that explains what I was after: [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780750665940) but please let me know if you found anything else.

Comment: Daniel Ruprecht has provided a more rigorous, mathematical answer, but I'll leave this here for reference - sometimes it's helpful just knowing what resources to look for.